# How to keep AVAudioSession opened more than 10 sec in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I want play a sound then more 10 sec in background. But when my objective-c application goes to background, then 10 sec audio is stopped and I can't play audio again. I have added keys to background and airplay in my plist, and I have this code in my appDelegate:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
    if(error) {
        // Do some error handling
        NSLog(@"Errrror");
    }
    [session setActive:YES error:&error];

    if (error) {
        // Do some error handling
        NSLog(@"error!");
    }
```

How could I keep AVAudioSession opened and play sounds after go my app to background?

Comment: you need to add the audio background mode to your Info.plist

Comment: I added this, airplay audio in background modes in info.plist. Is rare, because sometimes play the sound the second time, and the first time it showa:  AVSpeechSynthesizer Audio interruption notification: {
    AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey = 1;
}

Comment: you didn't mention `AVSpeechSynthesizer` - probably worth adding that to the question. what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sotty for not add this. I created another question then. I'm trying read a UILocalNotification with AVSpeechSynthesizer. and..Only heard once if not once. And this happens if I turn the screen off after 10 seconds